# Where should I use "might" when talking about possibilities?

Tags: modal-verbs

When talking about **possible** disadvantages, where I should use "might"?

> There are a couple of possible disadvantages to be aware of when you go
> camping. One **might be** that there **might be** no phone signals.

Should I use "would" to avoid repeating "might"?

> There are a couple of possible disadvantages to be aware of when you go
> camping. One **might be** that there **would be** no phone signals.

> There are a couple of possible disadvantages to be aware of when you go
> camping. One **is** that there **might be** no phone signals.

Comment: All are correct, but they reflect different degrees of probability, about the likelihood of having your phone and the likelihood that this is an inconvenience. Is not having a phone a disadvantage to everyone, or might it only be a disadvantage to some people?

Comment: Do you mean 'access to a mobile phone signal'? Surely you can always choose to take the phone with you. The third sentence says that you definitely _won't_ have access and that you _may_ find this a problem. Is this what you were trying to say?

Comment: Thanks for both of you. I edited the question based on your comments.

Comment: (After the edit) - The second version now has the meaning I gave earlier; the third, that it _would_ be a disadvantage, but the lack of signal is only a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the first "might".

The pronoun "one" in the second sentence refers to *possible disadvantages*, so "might" is redundant. There's no meaning difference at all between, "*There **might be** a possible disadvantage*" and "*There **is** a possible disadvantage*". The first is only different in that it's extra polite or deferential, not in meaning.

So your third version is the clear winner.